# Solution to the functional equation $f(2x) = f(x)\cdot\sin(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, functional-equations

Solution to the functional equation $f(2x) = f(x)\cdot\sin(x)$ ?

At first I believe that finding an answer to that equation it was going to be an easy problem, since this other equation $g(2x) = g(x)\cdot\cos(x)$ could be solved by $g(x) = \text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, but I have already tried many different ansatz unsuccessfully for $f(x)$ (real and complex valued functions), so this kind of innocent equation have already beaten me.

Hope you can explained how to solve it, but first of all, please display the solution to the problem (I need it to test solutions to other related problems), this because I am starting to believe that maybe it don't have a solution, or at least a simple one through standard functions.

---

**Added later:**

Reading your answers I understand now is far from be an easy question as I believe at first sight...

For some of you that ask me about additional characteristics for obtain a solution, I am aiming to find a solution $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$ analytic, since I was thinking about $f(x)$ as a Fourier transform... but reading the answers it looks I will never find its inverse neither...

As @Sangchul Lee explain in the comments, the equation:
$$s(2x) = s(x)\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
have been shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05442.pdf) to have a difficult solution:
$$s(x) \propto \prod\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(x/2^p)}{x/2^p}$$

Now, by letting $s(x) = f(x)\cdot q(x)$ such as:
$$ s(2x) = f(2x)\cdot q(2x) = f(x)\cdot q(x)\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
And following Wolfram-Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%282x%29%3Df%28x%29%2Fx) if I make the split as:
$$ q(2x) = q(x)/x \Rightarrow q(x) \propto \sqrt{x}\,e^{-\frac{\log^2(x)}{\log(4)}}$$
So given there is an existent $q(x) \in \mathbb{R}$:...

1. It is possible to replace $q(2x)/q(x) = 1/x$ in
   $ f(2x)\frac{q(2x)}{q(x)} = f(x)\sin(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ and simplify it to $f(2x) = f(x)\sin(x)$??
2. Does it means that the main question have at least as solution $f(x) = c\,\frac{\displaystyle{e^{\log^2(x)/\log(4)}}}{\sqrt{x}}\prod\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(x/2^p)}{x/2^p}$??? (with "$c$" an arbitrary constant)

Comment: You function mostly likely follows a trigonometric identity from that relation.

Comment: You can define $f$ arbitrarily on $[1, 2)$ and then use the functional equation to extend the domain to $(0, \infty)$. Therefore it is relevant if you look for continuous/differentiable/analytic/... functions, and on which domain (intervals, real numbers, domains in $\Bbb C$, entire functions, ...).

Comment: As an example, there is no (edit: nontrivial) *analytic* solution in any neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: The trivial function $f = 0$ is an analytic solution. Any other solution will not be analytic.

Comment: The really wild thing is that not only does $f(0)=0$ but also $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(2x)}{f(x)} = 0$ instead of $1$, and that is not an easy relationship to construct nontrivially.

Comment: I'd ask a new question, since the existing answer makes a good point that zero is the only continuous solution for the original.

Comment: I would recommend you to ask a follow-up question in a separate post rather than update your question, since it may render the previous answer(s) less relevant.

Comment: Anyway, any solution of your functional equation $f(2x)=f(x)\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ which is continuous at $0$ takes the form $$f(x)=c \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x/2^n)}{x/2^n} $$ for some constant $c$. Note that the product converges locally uniformly, and so, it defines an analytic function. It admits the factorization $$ f(x)=c\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)^{\operatorname{ord}_2(n)},$$ where $\operatorname{ord}_2(n)$ is the largest exponent $k$ for which $2^k \mid n$. So I am very skeptical that this $f(x)$ reduces to any elementary functions.

Comment: @SangchulLee I was reading about it on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05442.pdf) paper but I get lost... I will ask it on other question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Martin has pointed out how one might make wild solutions.

We will show that the only continuous solution to your problem is $f = 0$ when your domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed note that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \not \equiv 0 \mod \pi$

$f(\frac{a}{2}) = \frac{f(a)}{\sin(\frac{a}{2})}$

by induction we have

$f(\frac{a}{2^{n}}) = \frac{f(a)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin(\frac{a}{2^{k}})}$

Thus if $f(a) \neq 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$ we have

$|f(0)| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|f(\frac{a}{2^{n}})| = \infty$

which is impossible. Thus $f$ is $0$ at all points $a$ such that $a \not \equiv 0 \mod \pi$. By continuity $f$ must be $0$ everywhere.